# Children are rendering below container and reposition when clicked

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I've implemented the layout and drag/drop functionality from the Adobe Flex Dashboard example application in my application:

http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/devnet/dashboard/main.html

But in my app the pods initially render below the container to which they are added. When you click them they move to where they should be in the container.

Does anyone have any idea why the children initially render perfectly, but outside the container that actually contains them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. My skin class has a  using TileLayout, whereas the container itself did not.